# Output in a file a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file

I would like to input a variable to a text file in batch. I've tried a couple of things but I can't seem to find the proper variable. Can anybody help?

Here's my code:

```
echo.
echo List of all recorded wifi networks and their passwords:
echo.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile ^|findstr ":"') do (
    set "ssid=%%~a"
    call :getpwd "%%ssid:~1%%"
)

echo.
echo.
choice /M "Do you want to save results to a txt file?"
set path=%errorlevel%
if %path% EQU 1 goto save_to_txt
if %path% EQU 2 goto END


:save_to_txt
if not exist List.txt (

        echo Output of Wifi password grabber.bat > List.txt

    )
echo ssid: %ssid% pass: %%i>> List.txt
pause
exit /b

:END
echo This is the no area
pause
exit /b

:getpwd 
set "ssid=%*"
for /f "tokens=2delims=:" %%i in ('netsh wlan show profile name^="%ssid:"=%" key^=clear ^| findstr /C:"Key Content"') do echo ssid: %ssid% pass: %%i
```

Epicurieux.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `%%i` outside of the `for` loop. it is a temporary variable used by `for`. You don't need to use multiple labels either, just ask beforehand if you want to save to file:

```
@echo off & set outfile=
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if not exist list.txt echo Output of Wifi password grabber.bat>list.txt
choice /c yn /M "would you like log SSID results to file?
if not errorlevel 2 set "outfile=>>list.txt"
for /f "tokens=2*delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile ^|find /i "All User Profile"') do (
    set "ssid=%%~a"
    for /f "tokens=2*delims=:" %%i in ('netsh wlan show profile name^="!ssid:~1!" key^=clear ^| findstr /C:"Key Content"') do (echo ssid: "!ssid:~1!" pass: %%i)%outfile%
)
```

or without setting variables in the for loops and without the need for `delayedexpansion`

```
@echo off & set outfile=
if not exist list.txt echo Output of Wifi password grabber.bat>list.txt
choice /c yn /M "would you like log SSID results to file?
if not errorlevel 2 set "outfile=>>list.txt"
for /f "tokens=2*delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile ^|find /i "All User Profile"') do for /f "tokens=2*delims=:" %%i in ('netsh wlan show profile name^=%%a key^=clear ^| findstr /C:"Key Content"') do (echo ssid: %%a pass: %%i)%outfile%
```

Answer (score 0):

As a result of [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70563722/output-in-a-file-a-variable-in-batch#comment124823905_70563991), *(beneath the other currently existing answer)*, I searched my script personal collection for an example of something similar.

The following, *(which may fail if certain things do not match the specific criteria under which this was designed)*, is intended to return the Profile name, the Interface name, the SSID, and the password Key.

Other than the addition of the 'results to file' portion of the code, it is tested on Windows 8+ *[English]*

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "LDN=_tmp"
For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir "%TEMP%" /B /A:D /O:N 2^>NUL'
) Do Set "LDN=%%G%LDN%"
MD "%TEMP%\%LDN%" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe OS Call /? ^|
 %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "=="') Do Set "HT=%%G"
(Set LF=^
% 0x0A %
)
For /F %%G In ('Copy /Z "%~f0" NUL') Do Set "CR=%%G"
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /M "Print WLAN Profile results to file"
If ErrorLevel 2 (Set "FOD=CON") Else Set "FOD=%~dp0list.txt"
For /F Tokens^=2^,4^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN
 export profile key^=clear folder^="%TEMP%\%LDN%"') Do (Set "_=%%~nH"
    Set "{="
    For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%I In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /S /D
     /C %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /I /C:"<keyMaterial>"^
     /C:".*!CR!*!LF![\ \%HT:~-1%]*<\/SSID>" "%%H"') Do (Set "]=%%I"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        If "!]:~-6,1!" == "/" (For %%J In ("!]:~,-7!") Do (EndLocal
            Set "}=%%~J")) Else For %%J In ("!]:~,-14!") Do (EndLocal
            Set "{=%%~J")
        If Defined { (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%K In ('
         Echo(^| Set /P "=!_:-%%G="^&:"!" 0^<NUL') Do (
            (Echo Name="%%G" Interface="%%K" SSID="!}:*>=!" Key="!{:*>=!"
            ) 1>>"%FOD%" & EndLocal))))
RD /Q /S "%TEMP%\%LDN%"
If /I "%FOD%" == "CON" (Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F "Tokens=1,2" %%G In ("!CMDCMDLINE!") Do (Endlocal
        If /I "%%~nG" == "cmd" If /I "%%~H" == "/C" Pause))
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

*The file `list.txt`, if you choose to write to one, will be located along side the batch file, `%~dp0`, it should create it if it does not exist, or add to it, if it does.*